# ld: arch/x86/entry/syscall_64.o:(.rodata+0xe08): undefined reference to `__x64_sys_pid' make: *** [Makefile:1183: vmlinux] Error 1

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

I am trying to add a system call to Linux kernel. After executing the command "make -j[nproc]" this error is encountered.
Following are the commands executed:

1. vim hello/hello.c
   in this: SYSCALL_DEFINE1(hello,int, id){...}
2. Created a Makefile
3. Added hello/ to kernel/ certs/ mm/ fs/ ipc/ security/ crypto/ block/ hello/ to main Makefile
4. In include/linux/syscalls.h added- asmlinkage long sys_hello(int id);
5. In arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl added- 442     common  hello                sys_hello
6. make menuconfig
7. In make -j2 I am getting above error

Comment: Looks like you are doing something wrong. But since you don't describe what exactly you are doing (what you have modified), we cannot help you.

Comment: Which kernel version are you using? I have failed to find the one in which file `arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl` declares `pid` syscall or similar.

Comment: kernel version:  5.15.10

Comment: In that version the syscall number 442 is occupied by `mount_setattr`: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15.10/source/arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl#L366. So adding a custom syscall for that number is incorrect.

Comment: I tried make -j2 after adding to syscall number 449, but still getting same error

Comment: Rephrasing my [second comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75353912/ld-arch-x86-entry-syscall-64-o-rodata0xe08-undefined-reference-to-x64-s?noredirect=1#comment132972381_75353912): The error message is about `pid` system call, but there is not definition of that system call in the **original** `arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl`. It smells like it is **you** who adds `pid` system call into given file (probably, unintentionally).